# How to mock window.location.reload in app.js using karma 1.7 and karma-jasmine1.1

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

In app.js, I have code

> var app = angular.module(moduleName);
>   fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication, function(){
>           window.location.reload();
>       });
>
> ```
> function fetchData() {
>     var initInjector = angular.injector(["ngResource"]), $resource = initInjector.get("$resource");
>     return $resource(REST_URL + "/configurations").get().$promise;
> }
> ```

when I try to run karma test runner , it tried to hit rest url and errors out as "Some of your tests did a full page reload!"

Is there any way I can mock it or prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Angular- you should be able to inject the window via `$window`, and inject a fake window object the way you might mock other things.